# Create multiple instances of same bean dynamically with Spring

Tags: java, spring

The problem is to create n beans. The `n` is determined by a config. The config is just a simple JSON file:

```json
{
    "bean1" : { "property": true }, 
    "bean2" : { "property": false }
}
```

So when I parse `config` I get that `n = 2` and create 2 beans.

There is a way to dynamically create `n` beans with BeanFactoryPostProcessor ([how to get multiple instances of same bean in spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378023/how-to-get-multiple-instances-of-same-bean-in-spring))

However, In my case, I need to be able to inject config somehow, parse it, and only then create `n` beans. I don't believe that injection is possible with BeanFactoryPostProcessor.

Comment: Could it be possible to make a config method to takes in a list of properties, and then returns a list of beans? Then you could autowire the list?

Comment: I want to store properties this config in application.yml along with every other config properties. To clarify a bit I'm trying to create n jdbcTemplate instances

Comment: Why do you want to do this? 

You could still autowire a list of datasourceproperties, and then manually create the beans in a config method and then autowire a list of templates.